# Unable to read oldmessage list while getting new message in socket in Angular 4

Tags: angular, socket.io, concatenation

I am using socket.io for real time chat, and I am able to get message through socket when any new message sent but when I am trying to concat with oldmessage list then my oldmessage list showing undefined.

Soket in firing just  right after message sent successfully back to the database
I am using socket in

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.socket.emit('init');
       this.socket.on('message',function(data){
        console.log(data) // here new message is receiving when sent new message
       this.oldMessageList = this.oldMessageList.conact(data)// but oldmessage list showing undefined
})
```

}

Can anyone help me why it is showing undefined , How to concat it

Your help would be great

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with socket. It is a javascript tip.
You have to use arrow function. If not, `this` does not refer to what you think.

```
this.socket.on('message',data => { // arrow function here
  console.log(data) // here new message is receiving when sent new message
  this.oldMessageList = this.oldMessageList.conact(data)// this will refer to youtr class, so this.oldMessageList will be defined
})
```

or use old-school tip:

```
var that = this
this.socket.on('message',function(data) { // old school function using "that"
  console.log(data) // here new message is receiving when sent new message
  that.oldMessageList = that.oldMessageList.conact(data)// "that" is defined
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Let me do it